# Linux. Can packets pass libpcap by?

Tags: linux, libpcap, network-traffic

I am writing a linux program that controls internet traffic. In other words, how much bytes I have used while some amount of time. I use a Pcap4J for java (implementation of libpcap) and I have question about it. What happens if my program hasn't proceeded a package while a new one has arrived.
1. It slows down the download(upload) rate for the whole OS?
2. It skips a new one, and my program will never know that it passed by?

In other words, I've downloaded the 1G of data on my computer. How many bytes my program get: 100% or it may be passed my program by but still got the destination place!
And give me know if it is a bad idea to write a control traffic app using this lib!

Comment: Languages that have garbage collection (cough, Java) will eventually have the garbage collector called, and your program will miss packets while the garbage collector pushes your work aside.

Answer (score 1):

Your application loses packets. In your words, they pass by.

However, if your idea is to have a metric of how many packets went in and out of your system in a given time, there are definitely better ways to achieve it.

On Linux you can just do a script that does something like this:

```
DEVICE=eth0
RX0=$(cat /sys/net/$DEVICE/statistics/rx_bytes)
TX0=$(cat /sys/net/$DEVICE/statistics/tx_bytes)
while : ; do
  sleep 5
  RX1=$(cat /sys/net/$DEVICE/statistics/rx_bytes)
  TX1=$(cat /sys/net/$DEVICE/statistics/tx_bytes)
  echo "RX bytes: $(($RX1-$RX0))"
  echo "TX bytes: $(($TX1-$TX0))"
  RX0=RX1
  TX0=TX1
done
```

You can adjust times or whether is a parameter, I think you'll get the idea.